# Artikel nach Präposition bei Mehrzahl

Tags: grammar, preposition, definite-article

Ich würde gerne erfahren, wie die Regel lautet, dass es:

> Hinter **den** Früchten steht eine Vase.

heißt und nicht:

> Hinter **der** Früchten steht eine Vase.

Zumindest würde ich persönlich sagen, dass es mit **den** richtig ist. Nur habe ich leider keine Begründung dafür. Mit der Einzahl wäre es ja:

> Hinter **der** Frucht steht eine Vase.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Den" bzw. "der" ist keine Präposition, sondern der bestimmende [Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artikel_(Wortart)), der ebenso wie das Substantiv im Deutschen [flektiert](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-Art/Art-Def.html?MenuId=Word620) wird ([Näheres zum Thema "Flexion" in der Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexion)). [Präpositionen](https://web.archive.org/web/20190427081208/https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4position) hingegen sind im Deutschen nicht flektierbar. Die Beispiele zeigen das schön: Die Präposition "hinter" passt sich nicht an das Substantiv an, der Artikel hingegen schon.

Die Form des Artikels ergibt sich also erstens aus dem "Zwang" zur Flexion und zweitens der maßgeblichen Form (Numerus, Kasus) des zugehörigen Substantivs.

**EDIT:**

Im Beispiel ist der Numerus des Substantivs "Früchte" klar. Der Kasus hängt von der Präposition ab. "[Hinter](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hinter_nach_rueckwaertig)" kann mit Dativ oder mit Akkusativ stehen:

> Die Vase steht hinter den Früchten. (Dativ für einen statischen Zustand)

aber

> Ich habe die Vase hinter die Früchte gestellt. (Akkusativ für den Bewegungsvorgang oder das Ergebnis einer Bewegung)

Hier ergibt sich aus dem Sinn des Satzes, dass ein Zustand beschrieben ist, also ist Dativ korrekt. Der bestimmende Artikel für Feminin Dativ Plural ist "den", also ist das erste Beispiel korrekt.

Comment: Okay, vielen Dank. Ich habe dann wohl die Frage falsch formuliert. Sie müsste ja dann richtiger heißen: "Wie ist der korrekte Artikel von Früchten in diesem Beispielssatz?"

Comment: Danke, damit kann ich schon gut arbeiten. Könntest du mir noch sagen, wieso genau es **den** heißt? Laut deiner Tabelle zum flektieren ist es der Dativ-Fall (Plural). Jedoch kann ich dies wieder nicht nachvollziehen!

Comment: @Malmi: Das hängt von der Präposition ab. "Fieserweise" kann "hinter" sowohl mit Dativ als auch mit Akkusativ stehen, wobei sich jeweils ein unterschiedlicher Sinn ergibt. "Stehen" deutet auf eine statische Situation hin, es handelt sich also nicht um eine Bewegung oder deren Resultat. Mit Akkusativ würde es keinen Sinn machen, weil das auf eine Bewegung hindeuten würde. Es muss also Dativ sein.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Äh, es ist doch schnuppe, dass das Wort *stehen* ist. Selbst wenn das Wort *gehen* verwendet würde, ändert sich nix daran: *Der Fritz geht hinter den Bäumen.* Oder hab ich dich falsch verstanden?

Comment: @Em1: nee - Dein Beispiel zeigt das prima. "geht hinter **die** Bäume" (er bewegt sich dorthin) ist ebenso möglich wie "geht hinter **den** Bäumen" (er bewegt sich dort). Mit dem Verb "stehen" *geht das jedoch nicht*, denn da passt keine Richtung dazu, nur eine Ortsangabe: "Fritz steht hinter die Bäume" kann man zwar umgangssprachlich hören, ist aber im Hochdeutschen grammatikalisch nicht korrekt. Daher meine Ansicht: beim Verb "stehen" kann "hinter" nur mit Dativ stehen, das Verb gibt also im Beispiel die Form des Artikels zwingend vor.

Comment: @tohuwawohu Ahhh, verstanden :) Darauf wolltest du hinaus.

Answer (score 2):

"Früchten" ist Dativ Plural, folglich muss auch der Artikel im Dativ Plural stehen. Dieser lautet immer "den" (unabhängig vom Geschlecht).